# correcting a density plot while looping through columns

Tags: r, ggplot2, density-plot

**solved, just needed to correct the binwidth**

I have a database with almost 200 variables that I want to loop over and make 2 plots: 1 boxplot and one density plot. The density plot should differentiate in color between two groups in 1 variable
However, if you look at the attached density plot it seems to use the counts of the 2 groups together to do the calculations instead of using them separately; at least the density curves are way lower than the bars suggesting an issue.

Please find below the code for an example

```
rm(list=ls())
library(ggplot2)
library(purrr)
library(ggbeeswarm)
library(cowplot)
library(plotly)

group <- c("Control","PAD","Control","PAD","PAD", "Control","PAD","Control","PAD","PAD", "Control","PAD","Control","PAD","PAD")
b <- round(runif(15, 1, 7)) 
c <- round(runif(15, 1, 3)) 
d <- round(runif(15, 3, 8)) 
e <- round(runif(15, 1, 5))
event <- c("no event", "event" , "no event" , "no event" , "no event", "no event", "event", "no event", "no event" , "no event" , "no event" , "no event", "no event", "event", "event")

df <- data.frame(group, b,c,d, e, event)
df

rm(group, b, c, d, e, event)
```

## define a color to the groups used for the boxplot

```
df$color <- "color"
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  if (df$group[i]=="Control") {
    df$color[i] <- "Control" # in de column PAD, if the control is control give the color the string "control"
  }
}
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  if (df$group[i] == "PAD" && df$event[i] == "event") {
    df$color[i] <- "PAD with event" # in de column PAD, if the PAD has event give the color the string "event"
  }
}
for (i in 1:dim(df)[1]){
  if (df$group[i] == "PAD" && df$event[i] == "no event") {
    df$color[i] <- "PAD without event"
  }
}
rm(i)
```

## used for looping through the columns

```
expl = names(df[1]) 
response = names(df[2:5]) 

response = set_names(response)
response

expl = set_names(expl)
expl
```

## subset PAD and control used for plot 2

```
PADonly <- subset(df, group == "PAD")
Controlonly <- subset( df, group =="Control")
for (i in names(df)[2:5]){
  # used for adding the normal curve in plot 2 (PAD vs Control)
  xpad <- PADonly[,i]
  xpadmean <- mean(xpad, na.rm=TRUE)  
  xpadSD <- sd(xpad, na.rm = TRUE)

  xctrl <- Controlonly[,i]
  xctrlmean <- mean(xctrl, na.rm=TRUE)  
  xctrlSD <- sd(xctrl, na.rm = TRUE)



  p1 <- ggplot(df, aes_string("group",i)) + 
    geom_boxplot(show.legend = F) + 
    geom_beeswarm(aes(color = color), size=2) +
    scale_color_manual(values= c("Control"="#D85622", "PAD with event" = "red", "PAD without event"="#2D416D"))
```

**# this is the histogram where something seems to be off with the counts**

```
p2 <- ggplot(df, aes_string(x= i, fill="group")) + 
    geom_bar(binwidth = 0.1, aes(y=(..count..)/sum(..count..)), position = "identity", alpha=0.2, color="black") +
    scale_color_manual(values= c("Control"="#D85622", "PAD" = "red")) + 
    stat_function(fun=dnorm, args = c(mean=xpadmean, sd=xpadSD), color="#D85622", size=1) +
    stat_function(fun=dnorm, args = c(mean=xctrlmean, sd=xctrlSD), color="#D85622", size=1) +
    stat_density(aes_string(color= "group",i), na.rm=TRUE, bw = "SJ", geom = "line", position = "identity", color="#5785DF", size=1, linetype=2) +    geom_rug(aes_string(color= "group", x=i), col="#D85622")
    geom_vline(xintercept=xpadmean, linetype=2, color="red")+
  geom_vline(xintercept=xctrlmean, linetype=2, color="green")

  p_all <- plot_grid(p1, p2)
  p_all

}
```

[image: Example of the density plot]

Comment: hey Jens, thanks for providing the example. For histogram, you need to specify the x-axis, so do aes_string(x=i,fill="group"). I guess it's coloring by group?

Comment: So if you have two groups, to overlap histogram, do geom_histogram(bins=18, aes_string(x=i, fill= "group"),position="identity",alpha=0.4).. otherwise they just stack

Comment: Hi "Stupid"Wolf, it works when I leave out the density function, but I actually want to have that in there to do kernel density estimation. Is there a way to add that to the code? So a combination of the histogram density plot with a density curve

Comment: I sort of have the graph, but it now calculates the densities based on the counts of the two groups together instead of calculating them separately I think. I made an edit in my previous post and added both a picture and the code.

Comment: Hey Jens, sorry I missed your reply. I might have got this wrong, looking at your code, you need a histogram overlayed with a density plot? you got to do geom_histogram(bins=30, aes(y=..density..),...)

Comment: I have added an example of the output. it calculates the counts (densities wrong I think) the density overlay does not make much sense

Comment: Ok yeah... well, you really need proportions on the y-axis? I can write you a fix.. using some available dataset, unless you dput(DBPAD) then I can fix it for you.. Ermm maybe also edit your post :) To this specific problem, your looping's ok

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202336/discussion-between-jens-posma-and-stupidwolf).